# No name resolution on host running pi-hole

Tags: networking, dns, pi-hole

I have setup pi-hole on my raspian buster and it works as intended for clients (IPv4 and IPv6). The host on which pi-hole is running, however, cannot resolve any addresses.

My Pi has a static IPv4 address and my `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` looks like this:

```
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.178.11/24
static routers=192.168.178.1
static domain_name_server=127.0.0.1
```

From this `resolvconf` automatically generates a `resolv.conf` like this:

```
nameserver fe80:ba27:ebff:fe4e:c4ff::%eth0
```

But with it name resolution on the RaspberryPi does not work anymore (all other clients still resolve names correctly using pi-hole).

- If I remove at least one of the trailing colons (or both) it works and uses IPv4 to resolve addresses. For it to use IPv6 I need to add a colon after the first group (i.e. `fe80::...`).
- Likewise issuing `nslookup google.com fe80:ba27:ebff:fe4e:c4ff::%eth0` fails with `connection timed out; no servers could be reached`.
- Issuing `nslookup google.com fe80::ba27:ebff:fe4e:c4ff::%eth0` fails
  with `nslookup: couldn't get address for 'fe80::ba27:ebff:fe4e:c4ff::%eth0': not found`.
- What works is
  `nslookup google.com fe80::ba27:ebff:fe4e:c4ff%eth0` (notice
  the double colon at the beginning and the missing colon at the end).

I do not understand what is happening.

- What am I doing wrong in my configuration?
- Why does the generated resolv.conf only contain an IPv6 address and no IPv4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I had a typo in my configuration. The option for a static DNS in `dhcpcd.conf` is `domain_name_servers`. In my configuration the trailing `s` was missing.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to resolve a few LAN names locally (that is, on the Pi itself), just add those names to `/etc/hosts`, e.g.:

```
192.168.1.10   laptop.lan
192.168.1.56   printer.lan
```

If you want to run an actual DNS server, you could start by trying out [`systemd-resolved`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-resolved), which can be configured by editing  `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`. Depending on your needs, this could be sufficient.

Comment: I want to use the local installation of pi hole as DNS server